# Create a dict of dict with 2 columns and with values from a third column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe in python that looks like somewhat following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'tag':['php','image-processing','file-upload','upload','mime-types'] * 2,
         'probability':np.arange(10),
         'token':['check'] * 5 + ['imag'] * 5
}).set_index(['tag','token'])
print (df)
                        probability
tag              token             
php              check            0
image-processing check            1
file-upload      check            2
upload           check            3
mime-types       check            4
php              imag             5
image-processing imag             6
file-upload      imag             7
upload           imag             8
mime-types       imag             9
```

I need to crate a dicts of dicts and the values being probability. For example for `php`

```
{'php': {'check': 0,
         'imag': 1,
         ....},
 'image-processing': {....},
 'file-upload': {....},

}
```

I don't need the internal dicts in any order of the probability values. I can code this up easily but I need to know if there is any pandas trick that can be applied here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dictionary comprehension`:

```
d = {k:v.reset_index(level=0, drop=True).to_dict() 
           for k, v in df.groupby(level=0)['probability']}
```

Another solution:

```
d = {k: dict(v.values) for k, v in df.reset_index(level=1).groupby(level=0)}
```

---

```
print (d)

{'file-upload': {'check': 2, 'imag': 7}, 
 'image-processing': {'check': 1, 'imag': 6}, 
 'mime-types': {'check': 4, 'imag': 9}, 
 'php': {'check': 0, 'imag': 5},
 'upload': {'check': 3, 'imag': 8}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the fastest method:

Your example:

```
df.reset_index(level=1, inplace=True)
df_dict = df.to_dict('your_index')
```

Simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':['php','php','php','c'],'col1':['a','b','c','a'],'col2':[1,2,3,4]}).set_index('id')
df2.to_dict('id')
```

[pandas.DataFrame.to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)